# Retrieve angular params in laravel

Tags: javascript, angular, laravel

I was trying to retrieve angular post request params in laravel controller using request objects but I was unable to do so , can anyone help me with a good example for the same.

Comment: so what's your request look like ? atleast provide us how you manage ajax request ..

Comment: Use `$post_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`

Comment: Following is the function im using to retrive the request data and get the value that is to be stored in the database




public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->Input('name'),
            'email' => $request->Input('email'),
            'password' => $request->Input('password')
            ]);
    }



But by using $request->Input() im unable to retive it

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are posting the data like below on your angular ts file

On form submit

```
this.userService.registerUser(userForm.value).subscribe((data: any) => {
                if (data.status === 'success') {
                    this.user = data.data;
                }
            }, data => {
                this.validationErrors = data.error;
            });
```

Here `this.userService.registerUser` this used for data processing and its operations are below.

```
registerUser(user: User) {
        const body: User = {
            name: user.name,
            country_code: user.country_code,
            phone: user.phone,
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password
        };
        this.response =  this.http.post(environment.api_url + '/user/register', body);
        return this.response;
    }
```

Believe you have a route defined in route.php as well

```
Route::post('user/your_action', 'YourController@yourAction');
```

On your controller, make sure to use `Illuminate\Http\Request;` class

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class YourController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function yourAction(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->all());
    }
 }
```

Comment: basically im trying to send name from angular and need to store that into my database using laravel 
 my angular request:-
params = params.append('name','Aashu Singh');
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/registerUser',{ params: params },{ headers: headers}).subscribe(
      (response)=> {
        console.log(response);
      }
    );

Comment: AND IN MY LARAVEL im trying to retrive it but its failing 

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->Input('name'),
            ]);
        return response()->json($request->all(),200);
    }

this gives me a database error that my column value should not be null

Comment: @Aashusingh I updated my answer. The very first part shows how the form submission and how the service processing and sending data to the route

Comment: @Aashusingh please see your database structure and see what are all "NOT NULL". If there fields, you should pass values for those. Suppose, if you try to create USER with only name, there might be password or other fields which are not null.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur help , but the issue still remains the same  , when im hiting my api using postman then im aable to recive the parameter but when im hiting it by using angular HttpClient im unable to collect the parameters over my laravel there $request->input('paramname') returns me null

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to get my param data but it doesnt seems to be the right way

```
foreach($request['params']['updates'] as $params){
        Log::info($params['param']."  ======   ".$params['value']);
    }
```

i have to go deep in my $request array to get it , not so happy with this 
My whole $request looks like this :-

```
[2019-04-30 05:47:39] local.INFO: array (
```

'params' => 
  array (
    'updates' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'param' => 'name',
        'value' => 'Aashu Singh',
        'op' => 'a',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'param' => 'email',
        'value' => 'singhaashu14@gmail.com',
        'op' => 'a',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        'param' => 'password',
        'value' => '1234567890',
        'op' => 'a',
      ),
    ),
    'cloneFrom' => 
    array (
      'updates' => NULL,
      'cloneFrom' => NULL,
      'encoder' => 
      array (
      ),
      'map' => NULL,
    ),
    'encoder' => 
    array (
    ),
    'map' => NULL,
  ),
)